# Faster grep function for big (27GB) files

Tags: file, bash, awk, grep

I have to grep from a file (5MB) containing specific strings the same strings (and other information) from a big file (27GB). 
To speed up the analysis I split the 27GB file into 1GB files and then applied the following script (with the help of some people here). However it is not very efficient (to produce a 180KB file it takes 30 hours!).

Here's the script. Is there a more appropriate tool than grep? Or a more efficient way to use grep?

```
#!/bin/bash

NR_CPUS=4
count=0


for z in `echo {a..z}` ;
do
 for x in `echo {a..z}` ;
 do
  for y in `echo {a..z}` ;
  do
   for ids in $(cat input.sam|awk '{print $1}');  
   do 
    grep $ids sample_"$z""$x""$y"|awk '{print $1" "$10" "$11}' >> output.txt &
    let count+=1
                                [[ $((count%NR_CPUS)) -eq 0 ]] && wait
   done
  done #&
```

Comment: `input.sam` is the 5Mb file and `sample_???` are the 1Gb files? `sample_???` files seem to be `27^3 = 19683` files, not just 27.

Comment: Also, a couple of side notes. Bash already expands `{a..z}`, you don't need to `echo` it: `for x in {a..z}`. You can redirect input, instead of spawning `cat`, making it read the file, write it to pipe and then have `awk` read from pipe: `for ids in $(awk '...' < input.sam)`. In the same line, replacing `awk` by `cut` may be an improvement, since `cut` is simpler. In fact, moving that particular loop to the top would be more efficient since you are repeating that expensive operation many times, even though the end result is always the same.

Comment: Also, beware of `>> output.txt` in different threads. Make sure it is safe (I don't know if it is). If not, perhaps it would be a good idea for each of them to redirect to an `output-cpuid.txt` file and in the end concat the four of them.

Comment: Finally, since your operation is I/O heavy, dividing it in threads may not actually improve performance. If anything, it may even make it worse since you'd have more random disk read requests.

Comment: @Shahbaz I'd concatenate all the above into an answer, since it's all good stuff

Comment: @BrianAgnew, meh. Most of it is already covered by the other answers. Besides, it doesn't actually solve the problem, but they are just side notes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few things you can try:

1) You are reading `input.sam` multiple times. It only needs to be read once before your first loop starts. Save the ids to a temporary file which will be read by `grep`.

2) Prefix your grep command with `LC_ALL=C` to use the C locale instead of UTF-8. This will speed up `grep`.

3) Use `fgrep` because you're searching for a fixed string, not a regular expression.

4) Use `-f` to make `grep` read patterns from a file, rather than using a loop.

5) Don't write to the output file from multiple processes as you may end up with lines interleaving and a corrupt file.

After making those changes, this is what your script would become:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.sam > idsFile.txt
for z in {a..z}
do
 for x in {a..z}
 do
  for y in {a..z}
  do
    LC_ALL=C fgrep -f idsFile.txt sample_"$z""$x""$y" | awk '{print $1,$10,$11}'
  done >> output.txt
```

Also, check out [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) which is designed to help you run jobs in parallel.

Comment: it works!!!!!!!! And now it takes seconds instead of days!!! How can I say thank you??!?!?

Comment: @dogbane: it seems unefficient to have 27^3=19683 spwaning of fgrep. change the `LC_ALL ..... | awk ...` line into : `echo "sample_${z}${x}${y}" | LC_ALL=C xargs fgrep -f idsFile.txt | awk '{print $1,$10,$11}'` : that way only 1 fgrep and 1 awk are spawned. Changing fgrep to egrep may also speed up! As some implementations of egrep "compile" the regexp using a Finite State Automaton, greatly speeding up when having multiple regexp to look for. Especially for large files (as the time to compile all the regexp into an automaton is done once, and the speedier grep ensues on the large file)

Comment: patterns (-f) are bad ;) http://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/~schamane/_/blog:080727_grep_with_large_pattern_files. I am wondering how does it take seconds to grep 27GB file, may I know how many seconds is that exactly?

Comment: Description of how to grep n lines for m expressions: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

Comment: This would be faster still if you pulled the `grep` and `awk` commands outside of the loops (before the `>>`) so you only call each once rather than 26³ = 17576 times.  Just `cat` the file within the innermost loop.  Unless bash is smarter than I recall, you'll also need two more `done` commands to end all three loops.

Comment: While `-f PATTERN_FILE` is vastly preferable to the original, it may still be slower than `-E 'PATTERN1|PATTERN2|…'` (assuming a small number of patterns) due to [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and (though I can't find evidence for it in GNU grep) @OlivierDulac's noted egrep regexp compilations.

Comment: @AdamKatz :  see some evidence there : https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html (but as you note, maybe it's different between regular grep and GNU grep?)

Answer (score 4):

My initial thoughts are that you're repeatedly spawning `grep`. Spawning processes is very expensive (relatively) and I think you'd be better off with some sort of scripted solution (e.g. Perl) that doesn't require the continual process creation

e.g. for each inner loop you're kicking off `cat` and `awk` (you won't need `cat` since `awk` can read files, and in fact doesn't this `cat`/`awk` combination return the same thing each time?) and then `grep`. Then you wait for 4 `greps` to finish and you go around again.

If you have to use `grep`, you can use

```
grep -f filename
```

to specify the set of patterns to match in the filename, rather than a single pattern on the command line. I suspect form the above you can pre-generate such a list.

Answer (score 0):

ok I have a test file containing 4 character strings ie aaaa aaab aaac etc

```
ls -lh test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root pete 1.9G Jan 30 11:55 test.txt
time grep -e aaa -e bbb test.txt
<output>
real    0m19.250s
user    0m8.578s
sys     0m1.254s


time grep --mmap -e aaa -e bbb test.txt
<output>
real    0m18.087s
user    0m8.709s
sys     0m1.198s
```

So using the mmap option shows a clear improvement on a 2 GB file with two search patterns, if you take @BrianAgnew's advice and use a single invocation of grep try the --mmap option.

Though it should be noted that mmap can be a bit quirky if the source files changes during the search.
from [man grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

> --mmap
>
> If possible, use the mmap(2) system call to read input, instead of the default read(2) system call. In some situations, --mmap yields better performance. However, --mmap can cause undefined behavior (including core dumps) if an input file shrinks while grep is operating, or if an I/O error occurs.

Comment: Is that a 5% improvement ?

Comment: `--mmap` was [hot stuff](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) years ago, but it is no longer needed. It has been deprecated since grep 2.5.4 (2009) and **has been a no-op since 2.7 (2010)**.  Today, grep (version 2.22) doesn't even recognize the option.  Sources are scarce, but I used docs from grep 2.14, [GNU's d/l archives](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/), and [Red Hat Bug 1291714](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1291714#c0).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it would look like this:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.sam > idsFile.txt
doit() {
   LC_ALL=C fgrep -f idsFile.txt sample_"$1" | awk '{print $1,$10,$11}'
}
export -f doit
parallel doit {1}{2}{3} ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} > output.txt
```

If the order of the lines is not important this will be a bit faster:

```
parallel --line-buffer doit {1}{2}{3} ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} > output.txt
```