# selecting data from a big file

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cut

The following grep statement is working as expected.
But it takes a lot of time if the file size is too big (40GB)

```
grep '^INSERT' test.txt > new.txt
```

1) Is there any other way to quickly get the list of all "INSERT" statements from that file?

2) Is there any command to remove the first 100 lines from that file quickly?

Comment: What's your locale? `echo $LANG`

Comment: are your question 1 and 2 for same task or they are two tasks?

Comment: # local is # en_US.UTF-8 ## question 1 and 2 for same task. My INSERT statement start after first 100 lines

Comment: possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602963/faster-grep-function-for-big-27gb-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could string comparison instead of a regexp match but with a 40GB there won't be any magic command you still have to check every line:

```
$ awk '$1=="INSERT"' test.txt > new.txt
```

As for the second question use `sed`:

```
$ sed -i '1,100{d;q}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 sed -n '1,100\!{/^INSERT/p}' test.txt > new.txt &
```

You can send the process to background with '**&**' and continue with your work. Use **ps** command to check the status of the background processes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this off of a spindle disk? If so give SSD a try. Or if you can afford it get a machine with enough RAM to fit the whole file in there.

Answer (score 1):

The first operation should be much faster the following way:

```
LANG=en_US grep '^INSERT' test.txt > new.txt
```

(assuming you're currently using a locale with `UTF-8` support)